# Is it possible to create a method which is not contained within any class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I read a statement which says "*a method is defined and contained within a Java class.*" But, I am curious how definite is this statement.

Is it ever possible to create a method (function) in Java which does not contain within a class?

Comment: And how would you call it? Every method needs to be defined in a class, because there's nothing else outside classes.

Comment: Why do you have doubts?

Comment: @Dadou Because in C#, a `struct` can be used to replace a `class`. I think there is no `struct` in Java, but just to play safe, I want to check with all the experts here whether it is definite.

Comment: @user3437460 you may want to check with the experts, but simple questions like this don't tend to get answers from them.

Comment: "*... which is not contained within any class?*" does interfaces count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until Java-8, the statement about all methods "being contained within a Java class" has been entirely true. However, with the introduction of lambdas in Java-8 there has been an additional place where a piece of code might appear - a lambda function. Unlike an anonymous class which is still a class, lambdas are a different kind of code-hosting entity.

Java-8 adds another place where a method could appear - an interface. The new language addition lets you specify default implementation of a method inside an interface. It does not mean that you can call it, but you can certainly host some executable code inside a Java-8 interface.

As far as "free-standing" methods go, no language addition has allowed them: all executable logic must be container within *something else*, but not necessarily a class.

Comment: You mean Java 8, don't you? ;-)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, lamda functions are inside classes.  Interfaces are classes.  Regardless, interfaces always could have methods - it is just that prior to 8, all interface methods were public and abstract.

Comment: @emory Interfaces are definitely not classes (outside reflection, anyway). As far as lambdas go, it's actually pretty tricky: the compiler plays it smart, avoiding behind-the-scene class creation when lambdas are non-capturing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I will take your word about lamdas.  If we allow that interfaces are not classes, then there is nothing new about java 8.  we have always been able to create a mehod which is not contained within any class.

Comment: @emory Would you mind explaining how you would implement a method which is not contained within any class? Interface methods do not implement methods; method implementations inside anonymous classes are inside classes.

Comment: `interface Runnable{void run()}`.  the run method is inside an interface not a class (if interfaces are not classes).

Comment: @emory I did write "would implement", as opposed to "would contain", on purpose: I wanted to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

well...not totally. You can't do it at compile time, but you can do it on the fly. You can add bytes to a class on the fly. If you know the Java Virtual machine spec, you can do it, but i think you might also be able to do it with Apache's BCEL:

http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/index.html

There are also other options. Make your class abstract, and don't implement that method. make an interface. But, yeah, you could create the byte-code for a method and tie it to a class at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No, methods are functions for the Class and must be created within the Class.

Outside the Class, they're illegal.

Answer (score 0):

> But, I am curious how definite is this statement.

This is very definite.

No it is not possible. The methods should be there in a class.

And if you think logically also then you can find yourself that outside your class there is nothing. So from where you will call your method.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Because Java is and always has been object orientated, whenever a program is ran it is ran inside of a class to allow for easier creation and integration of objects. There are however some object orientated languages in which you can create methods outside of classes such as PHP. With PHP this is because it never used to be object orientated  but was changed to operate in an object fashion.